# android - loading multiple bitmaps with Picasso issues

Tags: android, asynchronous, bitmap, picasso, android-bitmap

I am trying to load multiple bitmaps from url using Picasso, and draw the bitmaps I load on my google map.

all of this code is in a google `MapFragment`.

```
public void drawLocations(final UserPictureUrl[] userPicsArray) {
    for (int j = 0; j < userPicsArray.length; j++) {
        Location targetLocation = ... // getting location

        // userPicsArray[j].getPicUrl() is the bitmap url
        loadProfilePicture(userPicsArray[j].getPicUrl(), targetLocation);
    }
}

private void loadProfilePicture(String picUrl, final Location location) {
    friendLoadTarget = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(counter), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                counter++;
                int width = 40;
                int height = 40; getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.profile_height);
                // drawCanvas draws the bitmap to the map
                drawCanvas(location, Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, false), picType);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        };
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(picUrl).into(friendLoadTarget);
}
```

**My problem is** - I have 3 bitmaps to load, but when running the app, the behavior of the loading is **unexpected** - sometimes it loads only 1 bitmap, sometimes all 3, sometimes 2 and sometimes none.

As you can see, I put a `Toast` to test if the method is actually called, and I almost never get all 3 Toast messages. sometimes only one message with "1" and that's it..

How can make sure all images are loaded properly?

Comment: Just to make sure, are you keeping that reference to the Target around somewhere? Picasso only holds a WeakReference to Targets. Also, is onBitmapFailed getting called?

Comment: Actually, that's it. You are probably replacing your Target reference, so you are only getting the last one to get called back. The others are gc'd. I would propose making your View or something else that stays around as long as the View implement the Target interface.

Comment: thanks! it really was that issue. ended up having an array to hold the targets references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Picasso` only holds weak references to `Target`s. You are losing the first two references when you loop there. You'll need to keep those references around for as long as you want to load the `Target`s.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I ended up having an array to hold the targets references. worked great!